# Travel in the Schengen area with only Carta d'identita and Permesso di soggiorno?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, passports, italy, permesso-di-soggiorno

I am a non-EU student in Italy. Recently I have left my passport at the UK embassy for visa. However I have a ticket to for Greece in the next days (with Ryanair) and  I the embassy doesn't give me a clear answer whether I will receive my passport by then. Now I would like to know whether I can travel to Greece with only my permesso di soggiorno and Carta d'identita Italiana (and no passport)?

Comment: I am not sure about the answer, but be careful with Ryanair. They often are more restrictive on documentation than needed. For example, I used to fly with my Spanish identification card between Spain and Belgium (I am Italian) but Ryanair insisted that only my Italian identity card (or a passport) will do.

Comment: You need to stamp your boarding card at visa check desk by Ryanair. Since you do not have the passport, most likely you cannot get the stamp and will be refuse to board.

Comment: @Rmano Because you are Italian, your Spanish ID isn't proof of nationality and therefore is neither a "national ID" nor, for the purpose of EU law, a "travel document".  (Legally, it doesn't matter whether Spain considers you to have Italian nationality, after all; only Italy is competent to make that determination.)

Answer (score 14):

Generally speaking travel documents for travelling within Schengen zone are: passport or EU/EEA national ID card. *Officially* none other documents are accepted, however some airlines might be more relaxed in their requirements. RyanAir is not one of these airlines, and RyanAir will **not** let you travel with just residency permit (I'm also speaking from personal experience).

Carta d'identita Italiana is not valid travel documents for non-EU citizens.

> Cittadini stranieri non comunitari
>
> Occorre presentare il permesso di soggiorno in corso di validità e il
>   documento rilasciato non costituisce titolo valido per l'espatrio.
>   [*(wiki)*](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carta_d%27identit%C3%A0_italiana#Cittadini_stranieri_non_comunitari)

Comment: the answer is correct, Italian ID cards released to non Italian nationals are not valid for travel outside Italy.