# Can I travel around the EU with an Italian resident permit (humanity), without a passport?

Tags: passports, europe, italy, residency

I have an Italian resident permit (for humanity reasons).

Can I travel around the EU with this resident permit, without a passport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travel in the Schengen area with only carta d'identita italiana and permesso di soggiorno](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34857/travel-in-the-schengen-area-with-only-carta-didentita-italiana-and-permesso-di)

Comment: This suggested duplicate doesn't cover the case of refugees.

Comment: No, not necessarily around the EU. However, you can travel around Schengen with it.

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to travel legally with *only* the residence permit (permesso di soggiorno). You also need your [titolo di viaggio per stranieri (refugee travel document)](http://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/31265). This passport-replacing document will allow you to visit other Schengen states visa-free for [90-in-180 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13183/3221), and also apply for visas to visit any other countries, for example the UK or USA.

This travel document should have been issued to you at the same time you received your residence permit. If you did not receive it, visit your nearest police station to apply for it.