# Travelling to U.K with Italian Soggiorno Ricevuta

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, italy

I am a student from India  studying in Italy.  My soggiorno has expired and I have applied to renew it. I didnt get the renewed soggiorno yet and I heard from the authorities It tooks another month to receive it. I have a U.K visa and I would like to visit U.K next week. Can I travel using the reciept of Application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travel in the Schengen area with only carta d'identita italiana and permesso di soggiorno](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34857/travel-in-the-schengen-area-with-only-carta-didentita-italiana-and-permesso-di)

Comment: @DumbCoder This is not a duplicate of that question, because the UK is not in the Schengen area.

Comment: What about Permesso di Soggiorno Provvisorio. I guess its a temporary Residence Permit. Dont know whether its valid or not!

Comment: @MJeffryes - He has an UK visa so no issue in entering and exiting UK. But that question does point out why it might be difficult getting back to Italy.

Answer (score 1):

You can return to Italy with your receipt, if the date of the receipt is less than 60 days from the date of expiration of your residence permit. Your flight must be directly to Italy without connecting in another Schengen territory.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in part:

> - Residents of Italy with an expired Residence Permit  are
>     permitted to re-enter Italy. They must also have a receipt
>     issued by the Italian Post Office or Police Department
>     proving that they have applied for the new residence permit
>     in less than 60 days after the expiration date. They must
>     return to Italy directly from outside the Schengen area.

Of course you must have a Standard Visitor visa to enter the UK. Your residence permit gives you no right to enter there.

Comment: The date of receipt is 4 days before the expiration of my soggiorno. Am a student, so I didnt have a permanant place of residence, which isnt required for students.